# How to get the public url of contentDocument in soql query

Tags: rest-api

How to get public URL of Content Document which is Uploaded on a record. How to get value in SOQL QUERY.I NEED THIS URL TO PUT  IN JSON

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306413/retrieve-preview-image-url-of-salesforce-image-files/306415#306415 answer your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please take our [tour] and review [help/on-topic] and [ask] to learn more about our format.